# If you only stun/snare/fear/(any other cc) an enemy, but gets killed by a tower, does it count as a kill?

Tags: league-of-legends

Let's say for example:

You're Fiddlesticks and you didn't harm the enemy champion for a while. Then you just `Terrify` (using Q, fearing him without dealing any damage) the enemy champion (which has 86 hp). The feared one walks right inside the tower range, then the tower shoots him once so the enemy dies.

Does this count as a kill or it's just an execution?

Comment: I belief status effects do count for champion kills.

Comment: I guess it would count as a kill because you still 'hit' the enemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though this was not always the case, CC effects and damage dealt to (but not enough to break) a shield *do* count for Kill / Assist credit.

Comment: But what if you don't deal any damage to the target, and gets killed by your turret after you applied a non-damaging fear spell to it?

Comment: That's exactly what I said. CC Effects, and damage dealt to a shield (which gets absorbed, and so deals no damage), both count. The shield change was recent, which is why I mentioned it. Previously, you could deal damage to a shield, the shield would fall, and the champ dies due to tower (or whatever), and you would not get credit.

Comment: As an addition, any skill that somehow modifies the champion's stat or behaviour will get you the kill. Any skill that does the same on an ally who gets a kill, will grant you an assist. I do wonder what would happen if you play as Janna, shield your turret and do nothing else while the enemy gets killed.....

Comment: @Joetjah I've actually seen that in ARAM. It counts as Janna's kill.

Comment: @Joetjah  "modifies the champion's stat". That means that if you use lux  'e' and slow the target but don't do damage to him, you will get the kill/assist? Without exploding 'e' I mean.

Comment: @David That should be correct, yes. An other good example would be Nocturne's ult, who usually got an assist just by darkening (and not flying). This has been changed though, but it was an example of how the system worked I guess.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Will it still count as a kill if you broke their spell shield or attacked them while they were invulnerable?

Comment: @LTPro Invulnerable, yes, spell shield, I don't know.